# Setting shell variables to contain file lists

Tags: bash, shell

I am using the following code to set up a variable containing a series of different file names, which I will then subsequently carry out some functions upon. The files involved are in a different directory (`DIRECTORY`) to the directory where the code is being executed (`CURRENT_DIRECTORY`). I thought the following code could be used to change into the directory containing the files `cd $DIRECTORY`, store the list of files in the variable `$FILES` and then change back to the original directory (`cd $CURRENT_DIRECTORY`) where the rest of the code can be executed. However, if I do two echo commands, the first contains the file list when I am in the directory where the files are stored, but the second echo command just prints `'vclist_2d_*.txt'`, i.e. it interprets this as a string and not a list of files (presumably because I have changed back to the original directory and so it can't find any files that match `vclist_2d_*.txt`). Why does this happen, and how can I get around this problem (without running everything in the same directory)?

```
#!/bin/bash
CURRENT_DIRECTORY=`pwd`
DIRECTORY=/home/Documents/NewDirectory/

cd $DIRECTORY
pwd
FILES=vclist_2d_*.txt
echo $FILES
cd $CURRENT_DIRECTORY
echo $FILES
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to save the result of the glob expansion.

Globs are not expanded in simple variable assignments so your current code is expanding the glob when you `echo` it (which is why you get the behavior you are seeing). Try `echo "$FILES"` and it won't expand at all for example.

Assignment to arrays, however, do expand so `FILES=(vclist_2d_*.txt)` will expand the glob immediately and then using `echo "${FILES[@]}"` later will work correctly.

Comment: I was going to post an answer with `FILES=$(echo ...)`, but I like your array solution better.

Comment: Could you explain why the `echo "${FILES[@]}"` syntax is needed.

Comment: That's expansion of all the elements in an array. Like `"$@"` but for an array. Unfortunately I don't see a good concise section in the bashref about this (which is odd).

Answer (score 1):

`FILES=vclist_2d_*.txt` does not get expanded by the shell. `FILES` now contains the string `vclist_2d_*.txt`.

`echo $FILES` sends `echo vclist_2d_*.txt` to the shell. The shell then expands the pattern, resulting in either A) the string `vclist_2d_*.txt` if the pattern does not match anything, or B) a list of the matching file names.

You then change the directory, and repeat the process. At no point is the list of files assigned to any variable.

Now, you *could* assign the *output* of `echo vclist_2d_*.txt` to a variable (`SOMEVAR=$(echo vclist_2d_*.txt)`, but that would solve your problem only halfway. How do you intend to "act on each file in the list"? If you are thinking about a `for file in $SOMEVAR`, consider what would happen if a filename contains a space...

**The easiest, most robust solution to this is to use `find` instead:**

```
find $DIRECTORY -name "vclist_2d_*.txt" -exec do_something {} +
```

This results in `do_something` passed a list of matching files. If the list is *very* long, it may be split into multiple calls of `do_something`.

```
find $DIRECTORY -name "vclist_2d_*.txt" -exec do_something {} \;
```

This results in `do_something` being called for each matching file.

If there is a chance that your *current* directory might contain files matching the pattern passed to `find` above, you need to escape the asterisk (by adding quotes like I did, or escaping it via `\*`) to avoid the shell expansion turning your `find` command into something else.

Comment: You have quoted the expansion in those examples. No globbing is being done so your final paragraph is unnecessary. Also you have what `\;` and `+` do backwards. `\;` is single-argument and `+` is coalescing. Using an array is perfectly robust for this as well and allows for things that using `find` does not (and conversely using `find` makes certain things easier than using the glob and an array does).